# Deleting a Row from grid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am adding a new row to grid using Viewstate Concept. But i cant able to delete the last row. By default i am bind an empty row to the grid.

// Add New Row

```
if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            int i;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox txtguide = (TextBox)grdreports.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtAccNo");
 dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtAccNo"] = txtguide.Text;
  }
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
                ViewState["rowcount"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count;
                grdreports.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                grdreports.DataBind();

            }
```

// Delete the Last Row

```
if (Grid.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
            Grid.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Grid.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
    }
```

Where i am wrong?

Comment: try  dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count-1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While deleting take the count and subtract 1 from that. It wil work.

```
if (Grid.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count -1);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
                Grid.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Grid.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable.Rows is a 0 based index. If you want to remove that last row you should use count - 1

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1);
```